# CSS Style lost in modal popup

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have an web application, I'm using modal popups for updating and inserting, I need dropdownlist without postback, so I put the modal into the update panel. It works but the html elements lose the css styles.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <%--Link para ModalPopup como TargetControlID--%>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake_BoxIng" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_BoxIng" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;">
            <div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; max-height: 750px; max-width: 1100px">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <b>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHeading_BoxIng" runat="server" CssClass="modal-title"></asp:Label></b>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-3">
                            <label for="ddlBoxIng_Filial">Filial Cliente</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoxIng_Filial" runat="server" class="chzn-select" Style="width: 170px;"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBoxIng_Filial_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-3">
                            <label for="ddlBoxIng_Depart">Departamento</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoxIng_Depart" runat="server" class="chzn-select" Style="width: 170px;"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBoxIng_Depart_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-3">
                            <label for="txtBoxIng_Cantid">Cantidad Cajas</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxIng_Cantid" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield" Style="width: 170px;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revCantNum" ControlToValidate="txtBoxIng_Cantid" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="Solo Numeros" ValidationExpression="(^([0-9]*|\d*\d{1}?\d*)$)"
                                Font-Size="XX-Small" ValidationGroup="BoxIng">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div align="center" class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfBoxIngId" runat="server" Value="0" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Crear" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="Cajas_Crear"
                                ValidationGroup="BoxIng" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="alert"></asp:Button>
                            <!-- UseSubmitBehavior="false" sirve para que se pueda ejecutar accion en el modal -->
                            <button id="btnCancelIng" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Cancelar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

        <%--mpeAddUpdateCaja Modal Popup Extender For pnlAddUpdateClienteDetails--%>
        <uc:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeBoxIngreso" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnl_BoxIng"
            TargetControlID="lnkFake_BoxIng" BehaviorID="mpeBoxIngreso" CancelControlID="btnCancelIng"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </uc:ModalPopupExtender>

    </ContentTemplate>
```

I'm using a master page, so that contains the scriptmanager. Please anyone have an idea? I'm not so good in javascript.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there could be multiple things that can be causing this behavior. Let me know if you have referenced your styles correctly and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Hi Jamshaid.... all my styles are referenced, none problem in the web console (F12), as I said, It works fine, but... If I put the modal into de update panel, It loses the styles.

Comment: Then I would suggest you put `UpdatePanel` inside the modal instead of putting modal into UpdatePanel.

Comment: where is the modal popup javascript code ?

Comment: Hi Aristos,
I'm using bootstrap, I only use javascript for close the popup with escape key:
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                $find("mpeBoxIngreso").hide();
                $find("mpeUpdateBox").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
where mpexxxxx are the modals of my page.